# Using a sequence and a trigger I auto incremented my table in Oracle10g, but the IDs are disordered

Tags: triggers, oracle10g, sequence, auto-increment

I entered 2 rows in the table-test, and got the ID in an auto incremented form, but when I entered the third record, the ID turned out to be 8.
On deletion of that record and entry of a new 3rd record, the ID turned out to be 9.

How do I solve this problem? I want all the ID's in a consecutive order, even after I delete a record or make changes.

Answer (score 1):

An Oracle sequence can never be guaranteed to produce a gap-free set of values.  You can minimize gaps by doing things like eliminating the sequence cache (which negatively affects performance) but you can't eliminate them.  Are you **really** sure that the presence of a gap creates a problem for you?  In every case I've ever seen where someone thinks they want a gap-free set of values, the right answer has been to live with the gaps rather than deal with the trade-offs of generating a gap-free sequence.

If you truly need a gap-free sequence, then you would need to force all changes to the table to be serialized so that only one session at a time can be inserting or deleting a row.  That massively reduces the scalability of your application and creates the potential for all sorts of maintenance issues when, for example, one session holds a lock while the user goes out to lunch or when the client application crashes forcing everyone else to stop working until the DBA finds and kills the offending session.  These are far worse than simply living with gaps in primary key values.

If you truly want to go down this path, you'd probably want to create a new table

```
CREATE TABLE my_slow_sequence( 
  table_name varchar2(30) primary key,
  val        number
);

INSERT INTO my_slow_sequence( 'TABLE_NAME', 1 );
```

In row-level trigger that fires before inserts (and update if you want to allow the key to be modified), you would need to lock the row in question (ensuring that access is serialized)

```
SELECT val
  INTO :new.<<pk_column>>
  FROM my_slow_sequence
 WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
   FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE my_slow_sequence
   SET val = val + 1
 WHERE table_name = 'TABLE_NAME'
```

In a statement-level trigger that fires after deletes, you'd need to go through the same process of locking the row in `my_slow_sequence`.  Then you'd need to either scan the table to determine what `val` to set or you'd need a row-level before delete trigger that captures the deleted `<<pk_column>>` values in a collection defined in a separate package that you could iterate through in the statement-level trigger.

If you want to allow the key value to be updated, you'd need a trigger or set of triggers on update similar to those you'd need to handle deletes.

Trying to handle this with triggers will involve quite a bit of code, many moving pieces, and will crush the performance of your system.  It's really not worth it.  Learn to accept that your primary keys will have gaps.